# Etas INCA Tool API - Add DataSet to workspace

Tags: python-2.7

Using Inca Tool Api, in python , I am trying to associate the DataSet (Working Page) to the WorkSpace, but in the documentation I do not find the method to make it.

In my case :

```
workSpace.SetExperimentEnvironment(experiment)
```

With this line, I can associate the experiment (created before) to the workspace that is an object of **HardwareConfiguration Class**.

The next step is to associate the DataSet and the Hardware to the workspace.

How could I do this ?